# How to disable html input readonly if user select that option?

Tags: html, readonly

By default the input area is set to readonly. Now I want that if user selected the Selection 3 the input area will now be inputable with text. How can I do this?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="selections">Options:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="selections" required>
<option value="sel1">
Selection 1</option>
<option value="sel2">
Selection 2</option>
<option value="sel3">
Selection 3</option>
</select>
</div>
<label for="textsection">Text to be edit:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="textsection" maxlength="34" 
placeholder="User can type here if he select option 3" readonly>
```

Comment: I would say with javascript you can use the `removeAttribute()` method in an `if` statement to remove the readonly.  Do some research and let us know what you tried.  Don't just ask us to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Javascript, select the elements (select and the input), add an Event Listener on your select element, then you can create a function to handle this behavior. Try something like this:

```js
const select = document.querySelector("#selections");
const text = document.querySelector("#textsection");
select.addEventListener("change", handleSelectChange);

function handleSelectChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    value === 'sel3' ? text.readOnly = false : text.readOnly = true;
}
```

You'll have to include this script in your HTML file.